# Django Form Fields Appear Dynamically

Tags: django, python-3.x, html, django-forms, django-templates

I have a form in my Django app that contains an upwards of 20 fields. It has been requested that I have only the first few fields display. Once those fields are filled out, the next few fields should be displayed, in addition to the previous fields. How might I accomplish this?

The following is my forms.py

```
class QuoteForm(forms.Form):
    premium_station = forms.IntegerField(max_value=2000, min_value=0, required=False, widget = forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder' : '# Premium Admin Stations Needed'}))
    standard_station = forms.IntegerField(max_value=2000, min_value=0, required=False, widget = forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder' : '# Standard Admin Stations Needed'}))
    basic_station = forms.IntegerField(max_value=2000, min_value=0, required=False, widget = forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder' : '# Basic Admin Stations Needed'}))
    messaging_station = forms.IntegerField(max_value=2000, min_value=0, required=False, widget = forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder' : '# Messaging Stations Needed'}))
    auto_attendant = forms.IntegerField(max_value=2000, min_value=0, required=False, widget = forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder' : '# Auto Attendants Needed'}))
    toll_service = forms.IntegerField(max_value=2000, min_value=0, required=False, widget = forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder' : '# Toll-Free Services Needed'}))
    receptionist = forms.IntegerField(max_value=2000, min_value=0, required=False, widget = forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder' : '# Receptionist Clients Needed'}))
    group_paging = forms.IntegerField(max_value=2000, min_value=0, required=False, widget = forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder' : '# Group Paging Needed'}))
    FourG_backup = forms.IntegerField(max_value=2000, min_value=0,  required=False, widget = forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder' : '# 4G Backups Needed'}))
    broadsoft_hub = forms.IntegerField(max_value=2000, min_value=0, required=False, widget = forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder' : '# BroadSoft Hubs Needed'}))
    polycom_410 = forms.IntegerField(max_value=2000, min_value=0, required=False, widget = forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder' : '# Polycom VVX 410 Needed'}))
    spa_122 = forms.IntegerField(max_value=2000, min_value=0, required=False, widget = forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder' : '# Linksys SPA122 Needed'}))
    yealink = forms.IntegerField(max_value=2000, min_value=0, required=False, widget = forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder' : '# Yealink W52P POE Needed'}))
```

My Views.py:

```
def quote(request, phonenumber):
    if request.method=='POST':
        quote = PBXQuote.objects.filter(phone_number=phonenumber).order_by('id').last()
        quote.premium_station = request.POST.get('premium_station')
        quote.standard_station = request.POST.get('standard_station')
        quote.basic_station = request.POST.get('basic_station')
        quote.messaging_station = request.POST.get('messaging_station')
        quote.auto_attendant = request.POST.get('auto_attendant')
        quote.hunt_group = request.POST.get('hunt_group')
        quote.toll_service = request.POST.get('toll_service')
        quote.music_hold = request.POST.get('music_hold')
        quote.call_recording = request.POST.get('call_recording')
        quote.receptionist = request.POST.get('receptionist')
        quote.group_paging = request.POST.get('group_paging')
        quote.FourG_backup = request.POST.get('FourG_backup')
        quote.broadsoft_hub = request.POST.get('broadsoft_hub')
        quote.polycom_410 = request.POST.get('polycom_410')
        quote.spa_122 = request.POST.get('spa_122')
        quote.yealink = request.POST.get('yealink')
        quote.ported_nums = request.POST.get('ported_nums')
        quote.new_nums = request.POST.get('new_nums')
        quote.directory_listing = request.POST.get('directory_listing')
        quote.save()
        return redirect('../../viewpbxquote/{}/'.format(phonenumber))


    else:
        form = PBXQuoteForm()
    context = {'form' : form}
    return render(request, 'Home/pbxquote.html', context)
```

And the form section from my HTML file:

```
            <section id="quote-section">
                    <div id="order-form-container">
                            <form class="login" method="post">
                                    {% csrf_token %}
                                    <h1>Quote</h1>
                                    <h2>Hosted Stations</h2>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="premium_station" class="sr-only">Premium Stations</label>
                                            {{ form.premium_station }} Monthly: $32.00 | One-Time: $8.00 Each
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="standard_station" class="sr-only">Standard Stations</label>
                                            {{ form.standard_station }} Monthly: $25.00 | One-Time: $8.00 Each
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="basic_station" class="sr-only">Basic Stations</label>
                                            {{ form.basic_station }} Monthly: $14.00 | One-Time: $8.00 Each
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="messaging_station" class="sr-only">Messaging Stations</label>
                                            {{ form.messaging_station }} Monthly: $4.95 | One-Time: N/A Each
                                    </div><!--Ideally, this would be where the first displayed section would end. As long as at least one of these values changes, the next section would appear, as it shouldn't be necessary for every field unwanted to be set to '0'.-->
                                    <h2>Services</h2>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="auto_attendant" class="sr-only">Auto Attendants</label>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="hunt_group" class="sr-only">Hunt Group Package</label>
                                            <select class="form-control" name="hunt-group">
                                                    <option disabled selected>Hunt Group</option>
                                                    <option value="1">Yes</option>
                                                    <option value="0">No</option>
                                            </select>
                                            <span>Monthly: N/A | One-Time: N/A</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="toll_service" class="sr-only">Toll-Free Services</label>
                                            {{ form.toll_service }} Monthly: $4.95 | One-Time: $14.95 Each
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="music_hold" class="sr-only">Music On Hold</label>
                                            <select class="form-control" name="music_hold">
                                                    <option disabled selected>Music On Hold</option>
                                                    <option value="1">Yes</option>
                                                    <option value="0">No</option>
                                            </select>
                                            <span>Monthly: $9.95 | One-Time: N/A </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="call_recording" class="sr-only">
                                            <select class="form-control" class="sr-only">
                                                    <option disabled selected>Call Recording</option>
                                                    <option value="1">Yes</option>
                                                    <option value="0">No</option>
                                            </select>
                                            <span>Monthly: $9.95 | One-Time: N/A </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="receptionist" class="sr-only">Receptionist Clients</label>
                                            {{ form.receptionist }} Monthly: $9.95 | One-Time: $14.95 Each
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="group_paging" class="sr-only">Group Paging</label>
                                            {{ form.group_paging }} Monthly: $9.95 | One-Time: $14.95 Each
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="FourG_backup" class="sr-only">4G LTE Backup</label>
                                            {{ form.FourG_backup }} Monthly: $75.00 | One-Time: N/A Each
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="broadsoft_hub" class="sr-only">BroadSoft Hub</label>
                                            {{ form.broadsoft_hub }} Monthly: $2.00 | One-Time: N/A Each
                                    </div><!--The second section would end here. This time, every field that is a select would either be selected "Yes" or "No", and the next section would appear.-->
                                    <h2>Equipment</h2>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="polycom_410" class="sr-only">Polycom VVX 410</label>
                                            {{ form.polycom_410 }} One-Time: $144.00 Each
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="spa_122" class="sr-only">Linksys SPA-122 ATA</label>
                                            {{ form.spa_122 }} One-Time: $34.90 Each
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="yealink" class="sr-only">Yealink W52P</label>
                                            {{ form.yealink }} One-Time: $129.00 Each
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="ported_nums" class="sr-only">Ported Numbers</label>
                                            {{ form.ported_nums }} Monthly: N/A | One-Time: $9.95 Each
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="new_nums" class="sr-only">New Numbers</label>
                                            {{ form.new_nums }} Monthly: $1.00 | One-Time: $1.95 Each
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="directory_listing" class="sr-only">Directory Listings</label>
                                            {{ form.directory_listing }} Monthly: $10.00 | One-Time: $20.00 Each
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Submit</button>
                            </form>
                    </div>
            </section>
```

I would greatly appreciate any help that can be given on this issue, as I haven't found anything online that, as far as I can tell, accomplishes what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can have two forms, one for the first half fields and the other to the rest. Then you just control which form you are passing to your template.
Haven't done it, but doesn't seem too difficult.
Another option would have a Javascript to hide the fields until the first half are filled, then unhide the second piece, and hide the first.

Comment: Hmm... I think this looks good. I think i'll likely use the JavaScript option, as I would need the user to submit another post request to update the context of the form to the template. Plus, it would involve rewriting all of the files, as opposed to just adding JavaScript. Thank you!

Comment: In retrospect, I'm not certain the JavaScript option would work. Any field other than a select tag is referenced using {{ }} (I have forgotten the specific name of the language), and I tried to find a function that would check to see if the value of the field is updated. The only things I found check to see if there is a difference from the initial value when a new POST request is submitted, whereas I just want the fields to appear when some answers are changed, without having to submit another POST request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a form wizard to accomplish this. It creates clean forms that do exactly what you need, and it's all with Django and python, no javascript.

First add formtools to installed apps.

Create multiple forms instead of just one:

```
class QuoteForm1(forms.Form):
    premium_station = forms.IntegerField(max_value=2000, min_value=0, required=False, widget = forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder' : '# Premium Admin Stations Needed'}))
    standard_station = forms.IntegerField(max_value=2000, min_value=0, required=False, widget = forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder' : '# Standard Admin Stations Needed'}))
    basic_station = forms.IntegerField(max_value=2000, min_value=0, required=False, widget = forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder' : '# Basic Admin Stations Needed'}))

class QuoteForm2(forms.Form):
    messaging_station = forms.IntegerField(max_value=2000, min_value=0, required=False, widget = forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder' : '# Messaging Stations Needed'}))
    auto_attendant = forms.IntegerField(max_value=2000, min_value=0, required=False, widget = forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder' : '# Auto Attendants Needed'}))
    toll_service = forms.IntegerField(max_value=2000, min_value=0, required=False, widget = forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder' : '# Toll-Free Services Needed'}))

class QuoteForm3(forms.Form):
    receptionist = forms.IntegerField(max_value=2000, min_value=0, required=False, widget = forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder' : '# Receptionist Clients Needed'}))
    group_paging = forms.IntegerField(max_value=2000, min_value=0, required=False, widget = forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder' : '# Group Paging Needed'}))
    FourG_backup = forms.IntegerField(max_value=2000, min_value=0,  required=False, widget = forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder' : '# 4G Backups Needed'}))
    broadsoft_hub = forms.IntegerField(max_value=2000, min_value=0, required=False, widget = forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder' : '# BroadSoft Hubs Needed'}))

class QuoteForm4(forms.Form):
    polycom_410 = forms.IntegerField(max_value=2000, min_value=0, required=False, widget = forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder' : '# Polycom VVX 410 Needed'}))
    spa_122 = forms.IntegerField(max_value=2000, min_value=0, required=False, widget = forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder' : '# Linksys SPA122 Needed'}))
    yealink = forms.IntegerField(max_value=2000, min_value=0, required=False, widget = forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder' : '# Yealink W52P POE Needed'}))
```

Then in your views you import from SessionWizardView, and specify the forms:

```
from formtools.wizard.views import SessionWizardView

class QuoteFormView(SessionWizardView):
    instance_dict = None
    form_list = [QuoteForm1, QuoteForm2, QuoteForm3, QuoteForm4]
    template_name = 'quote_form.html'
```

This way you can just use one template for every form, but if you need a different template for every form:

```
TEMPLATES = {
            '0': 'quote_form1.html',
            '1': 'quote_form2.html',
            '2': 'quote_form3.html',
            '3': 'quote_form4.html',
            }
```

Add get_template_names to your view:

```
def get_template_names(self):
    return [TEMPLATES[self.steps.current]]
```

Instead of the usual form.is_valid you use the done method to save the form:

```
def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
    data = {k: v for form in form_list for k, v in form.cleaned_data.items()}
    # Reference your data 
    attribute = data['premium_station']
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/redirect/')
```

And in your template you must have the management_form or it won't work:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block head %}
{{ wizard.form.media }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<p>Step {{ wizard.steps.step1 }} of {{ wizard.steps.count }}</p>
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<table>
{{ wizard.management_form }}
{% if wizard.form.forms %}
    {{ wizard.form.management_form }}
    {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
        {{ form }}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    {{ wizard.form }}
{% endif %}
</table>
{% if wizard.steps.prev %}
<button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.first }}">{% trans "first step" %}</button>
<button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}">{% trans "prev step" %}</button>
{% endif %}
<input type="submit" value="{% trans "submit" %}"/>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

## For reference

https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html#

Comment: Woah, that's incredible! I think I might use something similar to this after all! Thank you very much! :)